# Using properties of bijection for quicker proof of conjugate subgroup symmetry

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

My textbook, Szekeres's "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics: Groups, Hilbert Space and Differential Geometry", tacitly alludes to the following lemma, which I've tried to write out and prove on my own:

> Two subgroups $H$ and $H'$ are said to be **conjugate subgroups** if there exists\ an inner automorphism such that $H' = C_g(H)$ (that is, if the image of $H$ under that inner automorphism equals $H'$). Then the relation of being conjugate subgroups is an equivalence relation on the set of all subgroups of $G$.

My proof of the symmetry requirement is below, but it feels very long as I've "unravelled" both sides of the set equality. I have to imagine there's some more direct way to use that an inner automorphism is, in particular, a bijection of $G$. Can anyone provide that?

> **Symmetry:** If $H$ is conjugate to $H'$ then, by definition, $H' = C_g(H)$ for some $g \in G$. In particular, $H' \supset C_g(H)$, so for every $h \in H$ there exists an $h' \in H'$ such that $h' = ghg^{-1}$. That is, for every $h \in H$ there exists an $h' \in H'$ such that $g^{-1}h'g = h$. Thus $H \subset C_{g^{-1}}(H')$. Now we also have $H' \subset C_g(H)$, so that for every $h'$ there exists some $h$ such that $h' = ghg^{-1}$. Thus for every for every $h'$ there exists some $h$ such that $g^{-1}h'g = h$ so that $H \supset C_{g^{-1}}(H')$. Thus $H = C_{g^{-1}}(H')$ and so there does indeed exist an inner automorphism making $H'$ conjugate to $H$.

Comment: Assuming you use $C_g$ to denote the inner automorphism of conjugation by $g$, just apply $C_{g^{-1}}$ to both sides of $H' = C_g(H)$ and use that $C_g \circ C_{g^{-1}} = C_{g^{-1}} \circ C_g = \text{id}_G$

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Szekeres's "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics: Groups, Hilbert Space and Differential Geometry".

Comment: @math54321 Noted, thank you! I guess it just remains for me to trivially show that, indeed, $C_{g^{-1}} (C_g(H)) = H$.